# Empty InputStream after console I/O redirection

Tags: java, junit, console, inputstream

I have to test a program, where user have to enter 3 numbers and then he get result in console output.

I wrote test and redirected System.in and System.out.
My test cases look like this:

```java
private static ByteArrayOutputStream mockOut;

@Test
public void correct_input_test() {
    test("> x = 0, y = 0", 1, 0, 0);
    test("> x = -1, y = 0", 1, 0, -1);
}
```

Here's expected console output as first argument and 3 int args to prepare input stream.

**test()** method is below:

```java
private static void test(String expected, int ... args) {
    set(args);       // preparing inputstream and redirecting Sys.i/o
    run(expected);   // running program test after setting up
}
```

As many integer inputs are allowed as needed. These args passed further to **set()** method where I create an Input stream and redirect System.in
**set()** method:

```java
private static void set(int... args) {
    String s = Arrays.stream(args)
               .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));          // assembling args String
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()));  // redirecting Sys.in 
    mockOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(mockOut);
    System.setOut(stream);                                 // redirecting Sys.out
}
```

Passed arguments 1, 0, 0 became a **String s = "1 0 0"**

And finally after set I run method that invokes my program

```java
private static void run(String expected) {
    Main.main(null);                                              // call program to catch result
    String[] consoleLines = mockOut.toString().split("\n");       // split console output
    assertEquals(expected, consoleLines[consoleLines.length-1]);  // compare lines
}
```

Here I split on separate lines console output that I get in mockOut object and compare the last line with expected string.

**It works only if I test one testcase** (if I comment out any of these testcases).

```java
@Test
public void correct_input_test() {
//    test("> x = 0, y = 0", 1, 0, 0);
    test("> x = -1, y = 0", 1, 0, -1);
}
```

But if I try to run both after the second try to invoke program it gets an empty input stream with **java.util.NoSuchElementException** and I actually don't know why.
I've tried to close streams but I guess it doesn't matter. Each time I call **set()** I create new InputStream with non-empty args-string.
I also tried to restore default System.in and redirect it again in **set()** - no effect.

Could anyone explain what exactly did I forget?

UPD. I Separated my code to methods to explain which is which but in case it will increase readability - here is whole same code below:

```java
private static ByteArrayOutputStream mockOut;

@Test
public void correct_input_test() {
    test("> x = 0, y = 0", 1, 0, 0);
    test("> x = -1, y = 0", 1, 0, -1);
}

private static void test(String expected, int ... args) {
    set(args);       // preparing inputstream and redirecting Sys.i/o
    run(expected);   // running program test after setting up
}

private static void set(int... args) {
    String s = Arrays.stream(args)
               .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));          // assembling args String
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()));  // redirecting Sys.in 
    mockOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(mockOut);
    System.setOut(stream);                                 // redirecting Sys.out
}

private static void run(String expected) {
    Main.main(null);                                              // call program to catch result
    String[] consoleLines = mockOut.toString().split("\n");       // split console output
    assertEquals(expected, consoleLines[consoleLines.length-1]);  // compare lines
}
```

UPD.
Here is stack trace:

```java
java.util.NoSuchElementException: 

Arguments input incomplete.

    at Main.in(Main.java:169)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at MainTest$MainMethodTest.run(MainTest.java:75)
    at MainTest$MainMethodTest.test(MainTest.java:71)
    at MainTest$MainMethodTest$SwapMethodTest.correct_input_test(MainTest.java:29)
```

I know where exactly exception comes from.
Here is **in()** method that called from **main()** to get input from user and exception caught when Scanner tries to read **next()** from input stream:

```java
public static int in(String message, int from, int to) {
    if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(message);
    }
    try {
        String input = scanner.next();
        int num;

        /*         this code works correctly for me
                   and is just to check 
                   if user typed correct number 
                   and if the number is in range.
        try {
            if ((num = Integer.parseInt(input)) < from) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n\nExpected: value >= " + from + "\nActual:   value = " + num + "\n");
            } else if (num > to) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n\nExpected: value <= " + to + "\nActual:   value = " + num + "\n");
            } else {
                return num;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("\n\nExpected: integer number\nActual:   " + input + "\n");
        }
        */

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("\n\nArguments input incomplete.");
    }   // at Main.in(Main.java:169) - here is line 169
}
```

But I don't understand why IS is empty.

Comment: what is the stack trace of the exception thrown?

Comment: yeah, I updated the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Seems I solved it.

I just moved Scanner initialization from variable declaration to main().

```java
public class Main {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

And now it works for me.

```java
public class Main {
    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // ....
    }
}
```